# SEO Multilingual Sitemap structure

Tags: seo, sitemap, xml-sitemap, multilingual

I have noticed in a few articles that xml sitemaps for Multilingual websites are setup like this...

```
http://example.com/sitemap_fr.xml
http://example.com/sitemap_en.xml
http://example.com/sitemap_es.xml
```

Is there an SEO benefit or disadvantage for me setting them up like this...

```
http://example.com/fr/sitemap.xml
http://example.com/es/sitemap.xml
http://example.com/en/sitemap.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your Search Console setup:

- If you have certain GSC properties for every language subfolder, then it is OK, to place language sitemaps in their according subfolders.
- But if you have a single GSC property for the whole domain, then it is highly recommended to place all sitemaps into the root.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any SEO benefit, depends on you and your sites structure.

You can either list them individually under each sub-folder:

[image]

Or you can create a sitemap index place it on your root folder and list all you regional sitemaps or even a combination of both, personally i prefer having a sitemap index things are looking more well structured.